# Quick and easy way to see how many hits a heroku app has received?

Tags: heroku

I can see the logs for a heroku app with `heroku logs -t`

Is there a way to easily see how many hits an app has received in, say, the past 24 hours? (preferably using a quick command in the CLI, but otherwise through the heroku webisite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I see here

1. the Heroku dashboard provides you with a *Metrics* tab, where you can see the throughput of your application.
2. If this is not exact enough, you can add a logging addon ([logentries](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries) for example), then then analyze the router-logs there. Logentries provides you with counting, grouping, etc.
3. Same as a logging addon, but you also can add your own [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) and then analyze them yourself :)